# CocoaPods keeps asking for id_rsa passphrase after OS update

Tags: ssh, cocoapods

I recently updated my computer to macOS 10.12.2. Since the update, whenever it tries to read my `id_rsa`, it asks for my file's passphrase. This happens when connecting to my remote machines via SSH, but also when installing or updating my CocoaPods, which is where I first noticed this behaviour. It works after putting in my passphrase, but I'd rather have it remember it.

Any idea where I can change it back or what might have happened?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been answered on the Unix StackExchange site: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket

Comment: This update also broke this for me. What did you do @flohei? I tried the advise in that post, but it did not survive a restart and ssh is not working in cron jobs...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems there is some change in behaviour or bug introduced with the latest macOS update. I was able to resolve this by creating the file `~/.ssh/config` with contents:

```
Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Source: [Original answer at apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264963/52773)

Comment: I can confirm that `ssh add` does not survive a reboot, but updating the `config` file does. Thank you!